# View website traffic using a free service

Tags: website, hosts, traffic, google-analytics

I have a academic website whose host belongs to my university. My domain is something like this: `http://myuniversity.edu/~myusername/`. I want to view the website traffic using a free service. Unfortunately, [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com) doesn't work in my country. I was wondering if there is any such free powerful service. I googled and found some alternatives, but I don't know whether they are a good one or not. Besides, if I use some services like [alexa](https://www.alexa.com/siteinfo), it just shows me the traffic of `http://myuniversity.edu/`, but I want this: `http://myuniversity.edu/~myusername/`. Thanks for sharing your experiences.

Comment: I (like the other voter) voted to close because software / shopping recommendations are off-topic for this SE.

Comment: So, where can I ask my question? @davidgo

Comment: I edited my question. @Biswapriyo

Comment: Don't know which SE is suitable, if any.  Webmastes SE would be a better fit, but they also seem to have a policy against recommendations of external websites. Maybe you can restructure your question about how to collect analytics from your site without using GA ??   (BTW, Alexa is not the answer to your problem.  You either need to get the stats off your site from the uni, create your own stats, or use an external service which imbeds some tracking code - which is how Google works.)

Comment: Ask it in [Software Recommendation SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are even mildly flexible on price, you may wish to look at [Matomo](https://matomo.org), formerly [Piwik](https://matomo.org/blog/2018/01/piwik-is-now-matomo/) . It is a 100% open-source web analytics platform. While it does require a server to run some basic software, the tracking is done with a small snippet of Javascript (so the monitored pages do not necessarily have to run on the same server as Matomo).

> I want to view the website traffic using a free service.

It may be possible to run Matomo for free but (as a small hassle-saver) you may want to look at their own analytics service, which has (arguably) [reasonable monthly rates](https://www.innocraft.cloud/#pricing) currently.

That said, being open-source, you can set up your own service for as little as possible. The source code is free, based on common web technologies (PHP, Javascript, HTML, CSS) and the [basic setup is relatively easy](https://matomo.org/docs/installation/#the-5-minute-piwik-installation). As small caveats, it does require a MySQL database and PHP with [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions enabled for MySQL.

Regarding any costs involved with this second option, they likely rely entirely how you approach it :

- *University Servers* - If there is an opportunity to self-host on your university servers, this might be a good avenue to explore.
- *Free/Low-cost Hosting* - There certainly some free or low-cost hosts (a few dollars a month) that provide PHP and MySQL, but since PHP PDO support is technically optional, hosts may not have it enabled. Note that you can check PHP PDO and PDO_MYSQL support (both required) with `<?php phpinfo() ?>`. Simply place this in a *.php* document by itself, upload it to the server and navigate to the page it generates to see if these items are listed alphabetically.
- Web App Hosts - Web App services such as [RedHat OpenShift](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/3-piwik) (which has a [free tier](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html)) may be another option to consider.
- *Self-hosting* - For simple analytics, you may be able to run a minimal setup yourself (such as a Raspberry Pi or another older computer). This is obviously more involved as it requires running a small web server, but it's not impossible. PHP and MySQL are both free and  have solid support on Windows and Linux. Likewise, well-known web servers [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org) and [Nginx](http://nginx.org) are both free and have [cross-platform](http://www.apachelounge.com) [versions](http://nginx.org/en/download.html) as well. For your analytics domain, free [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) subdomains are available from a number of providers or you can use a [DotTK](http://www.dot.tk/en/index.html?lang=en) if you want a "real" domain at no cost (though a real domain will require a [free DNS service](https://www.namecheap.com/store/domains/freedns/)).

Comment: Does it work for `http://myuniversity.edu/~myusername/`? or it just checks `http://myuniversity.edu/`

Comment: Yes, it should work for `http://myuniversity.edu/~myusername/` specifically (not just `http://myuniversity.edu/`), assuming you are serving actual html pages you control (i.e. you can modify them, even by hand) and not just directory listings. It will (potentially) track any page you insert the appropriate Javascript snippet into.